# i want to find a different tags beautifulsoup python function

Tags: python, function, for-loop, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

this line: share_details1 = soup.find('a', href="../Industry/Industry_Data.php?s=100")
I want to also find instead of 100 or 200 or 300 0r 400 etc until 1300

example ../Industry/Industry_Data.php?s=200

```
def get_sector(ticker):
    soup = get_soup(LSE + ticker)
    try:
        share_details1 = soup.find('a', href="../Industry/Industry_Data.php?s=100")
        messy = share_details1.find("span")
        messy.decompose()
        sector = share_details1.text.strip()

    except:
        print('No sector information availible for ', ticker)
        return {'ticker': ticker, 'sector': ''}

    print(ticker, sector)
    return {'ticker': ticker, 'sector': sector}
```

Comment: do you know how to write a loop?

Comment: Edit your function to accept an additional parameter (100, 200... 1300), edit the `href` string to accept that parameter (see: `.format` function) and then write a loop outside of your function loops from 100 to 1300 (see: `range` function) in increments of 100 and pass that number to your function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to loop on a range you can do a **for _ in range(start, stop, step):**

Assuming you want it all wrapped in a function and you can accept the output to be an array of dictionaries:

```
def get_sector(ticker):
    soup = get_soup(LSE + ticker)
    result = []
    for s in range(100, 1400, 100): #starting here 's' is your changing value
        try:
            share_details1 = soup.find('a', href=f'../Industry/Industry_Data.php?s={s}') #plug in here
            messy = share_details1.find("span")
            messy.decompose()
            sector = share_details1.text.strip()

        except:
            print('No sector information availible for ', ticker)
            return {'ticker': ticker, 'sector': ''}

        print(ticker, sector)
        result.append({'ticker': ticker, 'sector': sector})
    return result
```